# search for character in string contains multiple characters in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, string, indexof

I have two strings are like this "L7 - LO" and "% L7 - LO"..

if string only contains "-" i need to some processing based  on this and if the string contains these two characters "-", "%" i need to consider only for % and ignore "-" character.

For this purpose i did like this below

```
   if (this.selectedSources[formula].Value.indexOf('%') == -1) {
    this.formulaType = "percent"
  }
  else if (this.selectedSources[formula].Value.indexOf('-') == -1) {
    this.formulaType = "diff";
  }
```

but some how the above code is not working ..

Could you please let me know how to differentiate only one character if there are two chars in angular

Comment: Do you have your logic flipped? What you have essentially says 'if not '%', then percent, if not '-', then diff. I would expect the test to be `if (...indexOf('%') >= 0) { this.formulaType = "percent"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if condition should be changed. rest is looking fine -

```
if (this.selectedSources[formula].Value.indexOf('%') !== -1) {
    this.formulaType = "percent"
 }
  else if (this.selectedSources[formula].Value.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
    this.formulaType = "diff";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test for both `%` and `-` in the string, I'd use a RegEx:

```
const regex = new RegEx(/.*[%]{1}.*[-]{1}/);
this.formulaType = regex.test(this.selectedSources[formula].Value) ? 'percent' : 'diff';
```

Otherwise, you can just use `.indexOf('%')`:

```
this.formulaType = this.selectedSources[formula].Value.indexOf('%') !== -1
  ? 'percent'
  : 'diff';
```